# I have a folder in a Github Repository. How do I "push" files into that folder?

Tags: git, github, repository

I have a remote repository in github. The steps I took are:

1. `git init //initializes git in current directory`
2. `git add * //adds every folder in directory to staging area`
3. `git commit -m "message here" //commits all files in staged area with message`
4. `git remote add origin remoteURL //add remote repository from github`

Now, with the final step:

5. `git push origin master:master //this simply adds the file to the main page of my github repository.`

How do I push these files inside an existing folder in the Github repo? I have a folder "Requirements" with a readme in my Github repository. I need to push my files inside there.

I'm sorry if the question is confusing. I tried to find solution to this, but could not.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a `git pull`. Then you should see the `Requirements` folder on your local machine, and you can put the files you want into that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't already have a local copy of the github repository clone it to your local pc like this:

```
git clone [link to repo here]
```

Then in your local area add the folder and files(s).

Right click on your local file, you will have Git options. One is likely to be a Commit option.

Then push back to GitHub.

You may find using GitHub Desktop easier: https://guides.github.com/introduction/getting-your-project-on-github/